# How do I export a hyperlink?

Tags: bugs, export, html, hyperlink

**Bug is present in version 11.2.0**

---

This fragment used to generate a HTML code for a webpage in which the `Hyperlink` showed up as an active link when viewed in a web browser. Now, with *Mathematica* 11.2 the link is no longer active. Have I overlooked something?

```
Export["~/Desktop/test",
 Notebook[{
   Cell["testing", "Section"],
   Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[
  Hyperlink[
   "Back to Interesting Science", "http://www.bgc-jena.mpg.de"]]]]
   }], "HTML"]
```

Comment: I confirm that the link in the HTML file exported with version 11.2.0 on Windows 7 x64 doesn't work . With version 8.0.4 it does work on the same machine. Obviously it is a bug, so I add the tag.

Comment: Related Wolfram Community thread: "[HTML Export Error in 11.2?](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1220050)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a workaround which works for me. On version 11.2, windows 7

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
If[Not[DirectoryQ["test"]],
   CreateDirectory["test"]
];

Export[
 "test", (*saved in this folder below current folder*)
 Notebook[{
 Cell["testing","Section"],
   Cell[BoxData[ButtonBox[RowBox[{"Back to Interesting Science"}],
       BaseStyle->"Hyperlink",
       ButtonData->{"http://www.bgc-jena.mpg.de", None}]]]
   }],
"HTML"]
```

And now the genenerated HTML works and link is active.

[image: Mathematica graphics]