# How do I export a list to Excel with links embedded?

Tags: export, hyperlink

I have two lists. One is hyperlinks, the other is the title for each link

I see that [there was a bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158752/how-do-i-export-a-hyperlink) in exporting this in 11.2

which I hope has been fixed. All I want to do is export to Excel my list of names with the hyperlinks embedded in them, a kind of merge operation

Here is a sample

```
Transpose[{shortlist, shortnames}]
```

Which outputs this

```
(*{{"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3053860/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0","The Chef's Wife (2014)"},{"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1073241/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_2","Nothing But the Truth (2008)"},{"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1226774/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0","In the Loop (2009)"},{"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8925546/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0","Getting to Know You (2020)"}}*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running v12.2.0, Win7-x64 and 2013 Excel.

```
data = {{"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3053860/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0", 
   "The Chef's Wife (2014)"}, \
{"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1073241/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_2", 
   "Nothing But the Truth (2008)"}, \
{"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1226774/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0", 
   "In the Loop (2009)"}, \
{"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8925546/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0", 
   "Getting to Know You (2020)"}}

dataexp = {Hyperlink @@ {Last@#, First@#}, Last@#} & /@ data

Export["C:/test.xlsx", dataexp]
```

[image]

Comment: If it is not inconvenient, please leave a helpful comment as you downvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
With[
    {
        links = {
                    {"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3053860/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0","The Chef's Wife (2014)"},
                    {"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1073241/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_2","Nothing But the Truth (2008)"},
                    {"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1226774/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0","In the Loop (2009)"},
                    {"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8925546/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0","Getting to Know You (2020)"}
                }
    },
    Export[
        "test.XLSX",
        Apply[Hyperlink,Reverse[#]] & /@ links 
    ]
]
```

[image]